# Is it possible for the function to be a solution of this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$y′′ + p(t)y′ + q(t)y^3 = 0$$ with $p, q ∈ C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$.

Is it possible for the function $$y = e^t −\frac{t^2}{2} −t−1$$ to be a solution of this equation?

I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $y_1=y,\,y_2=y',\,\vec{y}=\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}$ and $f(t,\,\vec{y})=\begin{bmatrix}y_2\\-p(t)y_2-q(t)y_1^3\end{bmatrix}$. Then we have $$\frac{d\vec{y}}{dt}=\vec f(t,\vec y).$$

Consider the initial value problem
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\vec{y}}{dt}=\vec f(t,\vec y)\quad \vec y(0)=0
\end{equation}

Note that $\vec f(t,\,0)=0$. So $\vec y\equiv0$ is a solution of this problem. Thus, $y(t)$ cannot be a solution to this problem due to $\vec f$ satisfies locally Lipschitz condition.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Plug these terms into your equation!
$$y(t)=e^t-\frac{t^2}{2}-t-1$$
$$y'(t)=e^t-t-1$$
$$y''(t)=e^t-1$$

Comment: Well, I get $e^t - 1 + p(t)(e^t - t -1) + q(t)(e^t - \frac{t^2}{2} - t -1)^3 = 0 \iff t = 0$, so $y$ is'n solution of this equation?

Comment: I will check your solution.